# mpchart piechart:how to show specific only one text value in android

Tags: java, android

I am facing one issue in pmchart piechart,i want to show only one slice,on compleltion of 100% progress of slice.you can see result in attach image

[image]

if i am using following code

```
 if (Float.valueOf(per)==100f){
            Toast.makeText(this, "100% completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            pieChart.setDrawSliceText(false);
            dataSet.setDrawValues(false);

        }
```

it is showing following result on 100% completion

[image]

Comment: Try this one... piechart.setDrawEntryLabels(false);
        piedataset.setDrawValues(false);
        piedata.setHighlightEnabled(false);

Comment: no.it is not working.

Comment: what is 0.0%? Is it pie value?

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: 2.2.4 and tried for 3.0.2 ....still it is hiding both value...i want to hide only specific one value

Comment: 0.0% is pie value of second slice.on completion of slice A(100%), slice B(0.0%))

Comment: Okey I got your point. When you creating a PieEntry arrayList at that time you have to checked. If(value is > 0) then add the value in arrayList else do nothing.

Comment: `String per=editTex.getText().toString();
  ArrayList<Entry> values = new ArrayList<Entry>();
   values.add(new Entry(Float.valueOf(per), 0));
   values.add(new Entry((100-(Float.valueOf(per))), 1));`  this is my code

Comment: See my answer this working fine with your case you need to check if(per > 0) then you add values.add() else do nothing and its working fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147891/discussion-between-andy-developer-and-user5607081).

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
piechart = (PieChart) findViewById(R.id.piechart);

piechart.setUsePercentValues(true);
ArrayList<PieEntry> yvalues = new ArrayList<PieEntry>();
// Write Your logic here.
```

Here you write your logic.

```
for(loop upto your values of list)
{
   if(your value > 0)
   {
     yvalues.add(new PieEntry("Your value", "Your Label", 0));
   }
}

final PieDataSet dataSet = new PieDataSet(yvalues, "");
piechart.setDrawEntryLabels(true);
dataSet.setDrawValues(true);

PieData data = new PieData(dataSet);
data.setHighlightEnabled(false);
data.setValueFormatter(new PercentFormatter());
piechart.setData(data);

piechart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
piechart.setTouchEnabled(false);
piechart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);
piechart.setClickable(false);
piechart.setRotationEnabled(false);
piechart.setDrawHoleEnabled(true);
piechart.setTransparentCircleRadius(10f);
piechart.setHoleRadius(35f);

data.setValueTextSize(13f);
data.setValueTextColor(Color.WHITE);

piechart.animateXY(1400, 1400, Easing.EasingOption.EaseInQuad, Easing.EasingOption.EaseOutQuad);
```

> Note: Above code is using the version of compile
>   'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.2'